# Doubt regarding ratios

Tags: ratio

Consider  a problem, there are three types of products X ,Y ,Z costing 532,504 and 486 bucks respectivel.A person buys A, B and C number of X, Y and Z respectively such that A+B+C is 37 and the average cost per product of the final mixture is 506.We have to find 'A'.

In the solution, they have found out the ratios, A:B=1:13 and A:C=10:13(I can understand till this part).Then, they have added the 'A' parts together(1+10)  and arrived at A:B:C=11:13:13 .I can't understand the method by which they have combined the ratios(usually L.C.M. of the no. of parts of the common component will be used).Please explain.

Comment: The correct answer is $A=11,B=13,C=13.$  I don't understand what $A:B=1:13$ is supposed to mean.  I would have thought it meant $B=13A$, but that's not true.  Can you explain?

Comment: @saulspatz Could you please explain the solution.Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you know the basics of modular arithmetic.  If you have trouble following any of this, please comment and I'll explain further. 
We have $$\begin{align}A+B+C&=37\tag{1}\\
{532A+504B+486C\over37}&=506\end{align}$$  Substituting the first equation in the second gives
$$\begin{align}
532A+504B+486(37-A-B)&=506\cdot37\\
(532-486)A+(504-486)B&=(506-486)\cdot36\\
46A+18B&=20\cdot37\\
23A+9B&=370\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

We have only one equation for two unknowns, but we haven't yet used the fact that $A$ and $B$ must be nonnegative integers.

Reducing equation $(2)$ modulo $23$ gives $$9B\equiv2\pmod{23}$$ and we find by trial that $$B\equiv13\pmod{23}$$  Since we know frm $(1)$ that $0\leq B\leq37$, the only choices for $B$ are $13$ and $36$.  Substituting $B=36$ in $(2)$ gives $A=2$ and then $(1)$ gives $C=-1$, which is impossible, so we try $B=13$.  Then $(2)$ gives $A=11$ and $(1)$ gives $C=13$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Nice answer. I understood most of it but why non negative integers specifically  means the remainder method can be applied. Why shouldn't we use it when A,B can be real numbers?

Comment: @Mohan When we reduce $23A+9B=370$ modulo $23$, we are using the fact that the remainder of $23A$ on division by $23$ is $0$.  This wouldn't make sense if we didn't know that $A$ is an integer.  To get to $9B\equiv2\pmod{23}$ we only use that $A,B$ are integers.  When we say the only possibilities for $B$ are $13$ and $36$ we use $0\leq B \leq 37$.  So I probably shouldn't have said "non-negative integers", but just "integers."